# How to remove %2F from the URL?

Tags: url

My Technorati URL shows as `http://technorati.com/blogs/www.financewalk.com%2F`.

How to remove `%2F` from the above URL so that it'll start working.

Comment: What generates the url to be like that?

Comment: Why isn't this as easy as typing it in without a slash instead of the %2F? http://technorati.com/blogs/www.financewalk.com/

Answer (score 4):

Having set your URL to `www.financewalk.com/` (mind the trailing slash), "technorati" will URL-encode (like JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent` function) that would result in replacing a slash with its encoded hexadecimal representation `%2F`.

So to change this, you need to change your URL to `www.financewalk.com` without a trailing slash. Then the resulting Technorati URL  will be `http://technorati.com/blogs/www.financewalk.com`.